# Adding coconut after fermentation

Tags: beer, secondary, porter

I am attempting to brew the coconut porter as listed in [this thread](http://www.jimsbeerkit.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=53901#p567509), which is bubbling away nicely at the moment.

It notes:

> after fermentation, rack off into PB or somesuch. 
>   Then toast 700g dessicated coconut in oven for 40min at 150C or until just turning brown - do not burn!! Add 100g of untoasted coconut to the PB with the 700g of toasted coconut - loose.
>   Leave for 10-14 days, giving a shake around every now and then as the coconut floats to the top.

After my fermentation is complete (I  usually leave my brew for 3 weeks,  no secondary) would racking it out onto the coconut, into a lidded bucket with no airlock, be suitable?

I've only got one fermentation vessel with airlock available, so I was planning on using my bottling bucket for secondary. It's just got a tight fitting lid with no hole for airlock.

Alternatively I can rack off into bucket, clean the fermentation vessel, then put the beer back in there with the coconut?

Comment: Or just add the coconut to your primary fermenter.

Comment: @Atron Seige, interesting suggestion! Do you think I could just ferment for 2 weeks in primary, then add coconut for 2 weeks in the same vessel? This seems like much less work.

Comment: that is what I tend to do. I have never used a secondary because the beer is not on the yeast that long. I would consider moving to secondary when you are leaving the beer for months/years, but for an extra week or two I would not bother. Autolysis is a problem when the beer is on the yeast for very long (for home brewers). Pro brewers have massive vessels that cause autolysis to occur a lot faster. I have brewed a fruit beer where I add the fruit on the second week of fermentation and leave it for a month. No issues.

Comment: @AtronSeige thanks, I'll probably go with that - sounds like much less hassle! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a good plan. I conduct secondary with low fermentable addition in closed lid buckets without problems. These lids are not perfectly airtight, and this imperfection is enough to let CO<sub>2</sub> out. Preferably use oldest (least tight) lid you have.

Alternative is possible, too, but it doubles the chance of contamination, and will double oxidation. I would avoid it - unless you expect vigorous fermentation after coconut addition. But I wouldn't do it. I'd rather unsnap lid a little to let excess CO<sub>2</sub> out, but still use no-airlock vessel.

Comment: Great, that confirms what I was thinking, thanks for your input ☺

Comment: Place the lid loosely on the bucket. You want it to hold out bugs and the like. If any CO2 is created it will lift the lid enough to escape and the lid will fall back in place. No risk of exploding bucket.

Answer (score 1):

How did this go?

I brewed a coconut IPA and used loose toasted coconut. The worst idea ever for beer.  I had to siphon out the beer through two vessels and use a screen to clear the big bits.  Next time, I will put the toasted coconut in a mesh bag.

What a mess it was.  Plus, I lost nearly 1/5 volume from all the liquid absorbed by the coconut.

Comment: It came out well! I did put it in a muslin bag though, to avoid exactly what you describe.  Things I found - my bag was too small, and the bag floated a lot more than I expected, will have to put some marbles in there too next time.